# Deploy docker container with java app to heroku return error ERROR [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=b

Tags: java, docker, heroku

I am deploy to heroku my docker container.
When i entered command:

'heroku container:push 6930970393a3`

I see building docker container, but build return

```
ERROR [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build /home/app/target/InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffSer  0.0s
```

All log:

```
C:\Users\kulik\InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService>heroku container:push 6930970393a3
=== Building 6930970393a3 (C:\Users\kulik\InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService\Dockerfile)
[+] Building 93.6s (11/11) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 480B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:11-jre-slim                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim                                                                                0.0s
 => [build 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim                                                                                            0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:11-jre-slim                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                         0.1s
 => => transferring context: 110.14kB                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/4] COPY src /home/app/src                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [build 3/4] COPY pom.xml /home/app                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [build 4/4] RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package                                                                                               93.3s
 => ERROR [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build /home/app/target/InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffSer  0.0s
```

How i can fix this problem? I reading manual https://devcenter.heroku.com/ but not find description this problem.

Entering command before:

`C:\Users\kulik>heroku login` 
Logged in as kulik7771@ya.ru

`heroku create` Creating app... done, ⬢ dry-island-35094
https://dry-island-35094.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/dry-island-35094.git

`C:\Users\kulik\InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService>heroku container:login`

Login Succeeded

this container works correctly on my computer in docker for windows

DockerFile

FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

COPY src /home/app/src

COPY pom.xml /home/app

RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

COPY --from=build /home/app/target/InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 8082

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

UPD:
I think problem is in name jar file. I read on habr.com what "Note that the name of the application must match the name of the artifact that is specified in pom.xml. Perhaps here you will have to spend some time selecting the name of the application, which is not yet occupied by anyone." but i don't undestand how to use it. And i don't find this information on https://devcenter.heroku.com/

Comment: Please post your docker file.

Comment: I added Docker file

Comment: These docker steps running on your machine or heroku server ? looks like on your machine, if on your machine, please try building image on your local and see if it gives the same issue.

Comment: On local machine docker build is successful. And container running successful too.

Comment: But your logs suggesting that its running on your local? No

Comment: I attached the deployment log to heroku. I used heroku client for deploy to heroku. this container successful run on local machine? but when i push container to heroku i get error.

Comment: I think, you are getting some permission issues or something, please check this [section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime) and try placing the jar file where non-root user can easily work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to apply your recommendations

Comment: I would build the jar locally, then your Docker file is simpler (no Maven) and just copies the jar file to run. If you dont want to build on you local machine the other option is to use GitHub actions. See an example here https://github.com/gcatanese/SpringBootService, hope it helps

Comment: @code_mechanic, thanks for the help!

Comment: @BeppeC  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't undestand docker container not starting, but i can running use GitHub.
For example deploy use GitHub:

`git clone https://github.com/Kulik1987/InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService.git`

`cd InvestmentAnalysisTinkoffService`   -folder with project from GitHub

`heroku login`

`heroku apps:create`   -create app in heroku

`git push heroku master` - load branch to app in heroku

That's all/ Your application must starting. See:
`heroku open` for open your application in browser or `heroku logs` if your application don't starting